# How to control the comparator to avoid the , inside the " " in a csv file

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am trying to sort the values by age and I get an error. There is a method in the program where it separates the values by ",". Upon inspecting the error, it seems that it also considers the , inside the string address (which it shouldn't do). Any ideas as to how I can make it ignore the , inside the double quoted values?

Here's the part of the code where I split the values:

```
while ((string = input.readLine()) != null) { // Reads each line and loops until there is no more text to be read

        String[] list = string.split(",", 8); // Uses "," to split the data
        String name = list[0] + "," + list[1]; // The parts of data is assigned their specific variable
        String email = list[2];// The parts of data is assigned their specific variable
        String address = list[3];
        int age = Integer.parseInt(list[4]); // Using parseInt, the data becomes an integer so comparison will be possible
        String residency = list[5];
        int district = Integer.parseInt(list[6]);
        String gender = list[7];

        person.add(new Person(name, email, address, age, residency, district, gender)); // Passes the information from the txt file
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Use a CSV parser instead.

Comment: Parsing a CSV with quotes and embedded commas is not easy. Use a library such as https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html to parse your data.

Comment: If your purpose is to learn or practice, you can have a flag `boolean isInQuotes = false`. Then you can iterate over the characters manually and toggle the flag whenever you encounter a `"`. Note that this does not work for nested quotes.